# Write a typesafe 'pick' function in typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash

`lodash` has the pick function which is used as follows:

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };
 
_.pick(object, ['a', 'c']);
// => { 'a': 1, 'c': 3 }
```

I would like to write a type-safe version of this in typescript.

Usage of this function should be

```
pick(object, "a", "b")
```

The goal is to conserve type safety.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Your pick function seem to have a different signature than the lodash example? What are those second and third parameters (particularly the third)?

Comment: I just edited this question to make the accepted answer (and indeed all the answers) apply to it.  It was originally written where the second argument was something like a callback that returned property values (although it was syntactically invalid, so not sure if that was the point). Changed it to a list of keys.  Hope that's okay.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Sounds like you might be looking for the [Pick type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html). Would something like this work for you?

```
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  const ret: any = {};
  keys.forEach(key => {
    ret[key] = obj[key];
  })
  return ret;
}

const o = {a: 1, b: '2', c: 3}
const picked = pick(o, 'b', 'c');

picked.a; // not allowed
picked.b  // string
picked.c  // number
```

Comment: Do you have suggestion how to get rid of any type here?

Comment: @DanZawadzki that depends. What would be the goal of doing that? As written, the `any` doesn't "seep" out of the implementation - it's just the easiest way to build up an object from nothing without making Typescript unhappy.

Comment: In my version I decided to use the partial function. Project configuration often disallow the use of any interface, hence I wonder how to avoid it, with out disabling the rule.

`const ret: Partial<Pick<T, K>> = {}` instead of `const ret: any = {};`

Comment: The only negative I see with that is that you also need to change the return type to `Partial<Pick<T, K>>`. If that's workable for you, though, sounds like a good solution.

Comment: Is there any library with this pick helper method implemented for us?

Comment: @DanZawadzki Based on the example about `unproxify` [in the typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), the response would be `const ret = {} as Pick<T, K>`.

Answer (score 5):

With [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) (es2019):

```js
function pick<T extends object, K extends keyof T> (base: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  const entries = keys.map(key => ([key, base[key]]));
  return Object.fromEntries(entries);
}
```

Comment: This seems to incur a type error because the return type of `Object.fromEntries` is

```ts
{
    [k: string]: T[K];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

here's mine, using `Object.assign()`

```
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(object: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    ...keys.map(key => {
      if (object && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
        return { [key]: object[key] };
      }
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: I like this solution because it avoids the use of `any`

Answer (score 2):

The lodash type definitions use `Pick` to propagate the props, so you don't have to define it manually. Just install them with `npm i --save-dev @types/lodash` or `yarn add -D @types/lodash`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ethan.Roday's answer, I made a few changes.
Using `Array.reduce` and get rid of `any` type.

```js
export function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]) {
    return keys.reduce((acc, val) => {
        return (acc[val] = obj[val]), acc;
    }, {} as Pick<T, K>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here mine, extending @Bayu Karnia answer:

```js
function pick<T extends Record<string | number | symbol, T>, K extends keyof T>(
  object: T,
  keys: K[]
): Pick<T, K> {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    ...keys.map((key: K) => {
      return { [key]: object[key] };
    })
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I managed to swap arguments + curry and finally types are good enough.
Will be grateful if somebody explains it:

```
const pick = <T, K extends keyof T>(keys: (keyof T)[]) => <R extends T>(obj: R) => keys.reduce<Pick<R, K>>((acc, key) => {
    (acc as T)[key] = obj[key]
    return acc;
}, {} as Pick<R, K>)
```